# Testing onActivityResult()

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, instrumentation

I have the following Activity:

```
package codeguru.startactivityforresult;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StartActivityForResult extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.startButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        this.startButton.setOnClickListener(onStart);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        int result = data.getIntExtra(StartActivityForResult.this.getString(R.string.result), -1);
        String msg = "requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode + ", result=" + result;
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onStart = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivityForResult.this, ChildActivity.class);

            StartActivityForResult.this.startActivityForResult(intent, R.id.child_request);
        }
    };
    private Button startButton = null;
}
```

And the following JUnit test:

```
package codeguru.startactivityforresult;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.UiThreadTest;
import android.widget.Button;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class StartActivityForResultTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<StartActivityForResult> {

    public StartActivityForResultTest() {
        super(StartActivityForResult.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        this.setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        this.activity = this.getActivity();
        this.startButton = (Button) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        this.activity.finish();

        super.tearDown();
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testStartButtonOnClick() {
        Assert.assertTrue(this.startButton.performClick());

        Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);

        Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor am = new Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor(ChildActivity.class.getName(), result, true);
        Assert.assertNotNull(am);

        Activity childActivity = this.getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(am, TIME_OUT);
        Assert.assertNotNull(childActivity);

        Assert.fail("How do I check that StartActivityForResult correctly handles the returned result?");
    }
    private Activity activity = null;
    private Button startButton = null;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 5 * 1000; // 5 seconds
}
```

As you can see, I figured out how to mock up a result using `Instrumentation.ActivityResult` and `Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor`. How do I check that `StartActivityForResult.onActivityResult()` properly handles this result?

Comment: No link with the question, but there is no need to write `Assert.assert*(...)`, since `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` extends `junit.framework.Assert` : `assert*(...)` is an instance method, and can be called directly.

Comment: @Vince Yes, I am aware of this. I personally prefer this particular usage since all of the `assert*()` methods are static.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use intents framework to mock the activity result

```
intending(hasComponent(DummyActivity.class.getName())).respondWith(new ActivityResult(resultCode, dataIntent));
rule.getActivity().startActivityForResult(new Intent(context,DummyActivity.class));
```

verify on activity result logic

Answer (score 13):

For testing onActivityResult() in your test class, all you need to do is:

1. Create an ActivityMonitor which catching ChildActivity creation and retuning the mock ActivityResult.
2. Simulating the button click which start the ChildActivity for result.
3. Do some assertion on status and the mock ActivityResult.

Sample StartActivityForResult:

```
public class StartActivityForResult extends Activity {
  private boolean activityResultIsReturned = false;
  private String activityResult = null;

  ... ...

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    activityResultIsReturned = true;
    activityResult = data.getStringExtra("result");

    ... ...
  }

  ... ...
}
```

Sample StartActivityForResultTest:

```
public class StartActivityForResultTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<StartActivityForResult> {
  ... ...

  public void testOnActivityResult() {
    // Get current Activity and check initial status:
    StartActivityForResult myActivity = getActivity();
    assertFalse(myActivity.getActivityResultIsReturned());
    assertNull(myActivity.getActiityResult());

    // Mock up an ActivityResult:
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", "This is the result");
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult activityResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

    // Create an ActivityMonitor that catch ChildActivity and return mock ActivityResult:
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(ChildActivity.class.getName(), activityResult , true);

    // Simulate a button click that start ChildActivity for result:
    final Button button = (Button) myActivity.findViewById(com.company.R.id.open_next_activity);
    myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // click button and open next activity.
        button.performClick();
      }
    });

    // Wait for the ActivityMonitor to be hit, Instrumentation will then return the mock ActivityResult:
    ChildActivity childActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor, 5);

    // How do I check that StartActivityForResult correctly handles the returned result?
    assertTrue(myActivity.getActivityResultIsReturned());
    assertEqual(myActivity.getActiityResult(), "This is the result");
  }

  ... ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My StartActivityForResult class in the original post is simply an example. In my real application, I have close to a dozen different Activities to test. Some of these activities return more than one piece of data. Your test code suggests that I have to modify the interface of each Activity just for testing by adding getters for each piece of data returned by the child activity. I don't mind the extra work of writing this code. I'm just not entirely satisfied with polluting the production code with code that is only used for testing.

Comment: These are just samples for showing how to test onActivityResult() and do some basic assertion, depend on your demand, you don't need alter your Activity class in all cases, for example, if all your onActivityResult() does is update some UI stuff i.e. a TextView, you can directly check the the updated text without adding any instance variable and getter/setter methods.

Comment: That's a good point. I imagine that most of the time `onActivityResult()` will modify the UI in some way, as you said.

Answer (score -4):

please refer the sites below. It will help you to solve your problem.
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html

http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-start-new-activity-and-getting-results

Comment: As you can see from my code, I know how to use `onActivityResult()` in my `StartActivityForResult` activity. My question is how to write a JUnit test to ensure that it behaves correctly.