# Call waitForMonitorWithTimeout() from a @UiThreadTest

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, instrumentation

To illustrate my latest problem with writing JUnit tests for my Android app, I wrote a simple example with two activities, `StartActivityForResult` and `ChildActivity`. The former contains a `TextView` (for display purposes) and a `Button` while the later contains just a `Button`. The `onClickListener` for the button in `StartActivityForResult` simply starts an instance of `ChildActivity`.

```
private View.OnClickListener onStart = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start button clicked");
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivityForResult.this, ChildActivity.class);

        StartActivityForResult.this.startActivityForResult(intent, R.id.child_request);
    }
};
```

Now I want to test this method using JUnit. So I wrote the following test:

```
package codeguru.startactivityforresult;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.UiThreadTest;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class StartActivityForResultTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<StartActivityForResult> {

    public StartActivityForResultTest() {
        super(StartActivityForResult.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        Log.d(TAG, "setUp()");

        this.setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        this.activity = this.getActivity();
        this.resultText = (TextView) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.result_text);
        this.startButton = (Button) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.start_button);

        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(this.activity.getString(R.string.result), RESULT);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);

        this.childMonitor = new Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor(ChildActivity.class.getName(), result, true);
        this.getInstrumentation().addMonitor(this.childMonitor);
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        this.activity.finish();

        super.tearDown();
    }

    @UiThreadTest
    public void testStartButtonOnClick() {
        Assert.assertTrue(this.startButton.performClick());

        Activity childActivity = this.getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(this.childMonitor, TIME_OUT);
        Assert.assertNotNull(childActivity); // <------ Line 51

        Button resultButton = (Button) childActivity.findViewById(R.id.result_button);
        Assert.assertTrue(resultButton.performClick());

        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.toString(RESULT), this.resultText.getText().toString());
    }
    private Activity activity = null;
    private TextView resultText = null;
    private Button startButton = null;
    private Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor childMonitor = null;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 5 * 1000; // 5 seconds
    private static final int RESULT = 69;
    private static final String TAG = StartActivityForResultTest.class.getName();
}
```

Running this test gives the following output:

```
codeguru@trolloc:~/src/java/stackoverflow/sscce/StartActivityForResult/test$ adb logcat -c
codeguru@trolloc:~/src/java/stackoverflow/sscce/StartActivityForResult/test$ adb shell am instrument -w -e class codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResultTest codeguru.startactivityforresult.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResultTest:
Failure in testStartButtonOnClick:
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResultTest.testStartButtonOnClick(StartActivityForResultTest.java:51)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.access$000(InstrumentationTestCase.java:36)
    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase$2.run(InstrumentationTestCase.java:189)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1602)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Test results for InstrumentationTestRunner=.F
Time: 3.248

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1,  Errors: 0


codeguru@trolloc:~/src/java/stackoverflow/sscce/StartActivityForResult/test$ adb logcat -d codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResultTest:D codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResult:D codeguru.startactivityforresult.ChildActivity:D *:S
D/codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResultTest(  954): setUp()
D/codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResult(  954): onCreate()
D/codeguru.startactivityforresult.StartActivityForResult(  954): Start button clicked
layne@trolloc:~/src/java/stackoverflow/sscce/StartActivityForResult/test$
```

As far as I can tell, calling `startButton.performClick()` doesn't start an instance of `ChildActivity`. What gives?

Comment: The correct way of simulating a button click in Android JUnit Test is calling `button.performClick();` on application's UI thread, see example in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041890/testing-that-an-activity-returns-the-expected-result/13113137#13113137). I don't think by simply calling `Assert.assertTrue(this.startButton.performClick());` will cause the button actually been clicked.

Comment: @yorkw That test case is annotated with `@UiThreadTestCase`, so it runs on the UI thread automagically. The real problem is that I also call `waitForMonitorWithTimeout()` on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in [an answer to one of my related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041890/testing-that-an-activity-returns-the-expected-result/13113137#13113137), the problem is that I am calling `waitForMonitorWithTimeout()` on the UI Thread. After realizing this, it certainly makes complete sense because `waitForMonitorWithTimeout()` waits for the UI thread to complete some action (namely displaying an Activity's UI). However, by calling it on the UI thread, I am delaying that action from occuring.

Comment: Nice shot, something that hasn't been well documented in the official API doc.

Comment: @yorkw I'm disappointed with the Android API docs in general for not stating details such as this. It's a little bit frustrating. ;-(